# Hibernate one-to-one mapping with subclass composite column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two tables,1st table contains company_id, company_name and country name and second table contain company related detail with one to one mapping.

I want to do the following mapping using hibernate :-

```
        company {
          company_id int,
          company_name varchar,
          country varchar
        }

        company_detail {
          id int,
          company_id int,
          company_description text,
          future_goal text
        }
```

Company_id of company table should map with company_id of company_detail table so I have set following mapping in POJO

```
     In Company POJO :-
         @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
         @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")  
         private CompanyDetails companyDetails;

        In CompanyDetails POJO :-
        @Column(name="COMPANY_ID", nullable=false)  
        public Company company;
```

Also, add following code in setter:-

```
public void setCompanyDetails(CompanyDetails companyDetails) {
        companyDetails.setCompany(this);
        this.companyDetails = companyDetails;
    }
```

This code working fine, Only one problem coming while saving the company, null is storing in company_id of company_detal instead of company id which is created in company table. All other details storing properly.
So how to set one-to-one mapping in POJO for above table structure?

Answer (score 1):

***Edited :***

if you want to generate separate primary key for CompanyDetail , then it is as simple as below

```
 @Id  
 @GeneratedValue  
 @Column(name="COMPANY_DETAIL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false) 
 public int companyDetailId;

 @OneToOne  
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")  
 public Company company;
```

***######################################################################***

Refer this link [hibernate-jpa-onetoone-association-by-common-primary-ke](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/08/hibernate-jpa-onetoone-association-by-common-primary-key.html)

You must use a shared primary key generator in your companyDetail something like below

```
 @Id  
 @GeneratedValue(generator="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator")  
 @GenericGenerator(name="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator",strategy="foreign",parameters = @Parameter(name="property", value="company"))  
 @Column(name="COMPANY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)  
 public int companyId;

 @OneToOne  
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
 public Company company;
```

And in you Company

```
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName="Company_ID")  
  public CompanyDetail companyDetail
```

Also make sure you set the company value CompanyDetail and companyDetail value in Company as below,

In Company

```
public void setCompanyDetail(CompanyDetail companyDetail){
   companyDetail.setCompany(this);
   this.companyDetail = companyDetail;
}
```

similarly in CompanyDetail

```
public void setCompany(Company company){
   company.setCompanyDetail(this);
   this.company = company;
}
```

Comment: I also want auto generated row id in company detail table.
In that case what changes needed?

Comment: you mean you want generate separate primary key for CompanyDetail

Comment: Yes, Sagar. I want a separate primary key for CompanyDetail

Comment: It is not working. ERROR: null value in column "company_id" violates not-null constraint
Exception coming on company save.

Comment: use cascade on the relationship change setters as i mentioned  , add @GenerateValue to companyId in Company as well

Comment: Sagar, I do not understand - use cascade on the relationship change setters as i mentioned.Can you please explain it.

Comment: can you update your change in the post in both Company and CompanyDetail.. i will update it ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128931/discussion-between-gourav-saklecha-and-sagar).

Comment: Sagar, It is creating a new row in child table on company update.

Comment: I do not understand your scenario completely .. but when you update you company the child entry (companyDetails) in your company should be persisted object meaning it should have it primaryKey if not the hibernate will insert it as a new row ... elaborate your situation

Comment: When I fetch the company, It brings CompanyDetail null.